# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get all pens when are not blue by using below
expression. there are two lists pens and bluepens...

```
var pensToDelete = _repository.GetPens().Where(x => bluePens.All(y => y.Id != x.Id));
```

when I am accessing pensToDelete  as below

```
if (pensToDelete .Count() > 0)
{
}
```

I get the below error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(a => __bluePens_0
> .All(y => y.Id != a.Id))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use an expression in LINQ it must be translatable to the underlying provider when you get `InvalidOperationException` it may because of failed translating the `LINQ` expression to equivalent `SQL Query`.

As we discussed in comments be careful when you want using `ToList()`, always try to use it after your main query because it is costly and retrieve all the records before anything something like `Where().Tolist()` not `ToList().Where()`

How about this:

```
var pensToDelete = _repository.GetPens()
                              .Where(x => !bluePens.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(x.Id));
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, is the `ToArray` required?

Comment: Nope, Because `Select` itself is an `Enumerable` and already have `Contains`, Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I knew it wouldn't be required if it was executing in memory, but wasn't sure enough to say it wouldn't when SQL translation is involved - sometimes throws the odd surprise out!

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be resolved rather quickly, as mentioned in the error message by using enumerating the results by using e.g.: `ToList`.

The downside of this is that it will be processed in memory and not in your SQL server.

If that is acceptable, this is how to do it;

```
var pensToDelete = _repository.GetPens().ToList()
                              .Where(x => bluePens.All(y => y.Id != x.Id));
```

Comment: `ToList()` is very costly and retrieve all records from Db firstly, can we `join` all `bluePens` with `GetPens()` or `not in` ?

Comment: Correct. If this cost to much, we need a `not in` SQL equivalent

Comment: If it's expensive, how to write that not in query?

Comment: See @Aria's answer for that :-)